# Object position misplaced when i set a angle to background image in fabric

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

i can able to set a background image by using following code

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(imageSource, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
  // Fixed  object misplacing issue.
  top: obj.top, // object top
  left: obj.left, // object left
  width: obj.width * obj.scaleX,
  height: obj.height * obj.scaleY,
  name: 'back-img',
  originX: obj.originX,
  originY: obj.originY,
  // angle:angle,
  srno: "" // removed serial number of background image. because serial number is undefined

});
```

when i set angle to background image, the image position misplaced.
I have tried

```
canvas.backgroundImage.setAngle(45)
```

above code did not work because `canvas.setBackgroundImage` is synchronous function 
Thank you for your answer